# Carousel not working in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, html, jcarousel, carousel

I am working with jquery.carouFredSel-4.0.3-packed.js for the carousal and it works good with IE9 and mozilla,but in IE7/8, it says "LOG: carouFredSel: Not enough items: not scrolling " whenever i am seeing it is not the case.

The code i am using is

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="mask">
        <a class="arrow left off"><-</a>
        <a class="arrow left on" href="javascript:void(0);"><-</a>
        <ul>
            <dsp:droplet name="ForEach">
                <dsp:param name="array" value="${listRecommended}"/>
                <dsp:oparam name="empty">no recommended apps</dsp:oparam>
                <dsp:oparam name="output">
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="${resourcePath}/images/apps/carousel-image1.jpg" alt="bakery story"/></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><dsp:valueof param="element.displayName"/></a><br/>
                        <dsp:getvalueof var="averageRating" param="element.averageRating"/>
                        <dsp:getvalueof var="rating" param="count"/>
                        <div class="rating">
                             <div class="medium">
                                <dsp:droplet name="For">
                                    <dsp:param name="howMany" value="${averageRating}"/>
                                    <dsp:oparam name="output">
                                        <input checked="checked" class="star {split:1}" disabled="disabled" name="product-similar-'${rating}'" type="radio">
                                    </dsp:oparam>
                                </dsp:droplet>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </dsp:oparam>
            </dsp:droplet>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="arrow right off">-></a>
    <a class="arrow right on" href="javascript:void(0);">-></a>
</div>
```

and javascript library is jquery.carouFredSel-4.0.3-packed.js.

Please let me know if someone has faced similar problem.

thanks in advance
Hemish

Comment: I've just formatted your code into a block and noticed that you have two closing `</ul>` tags. Could that be the problem? Does your full page [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: Hi andyb, this has solved the problem. thank you.

Comment: @cwallenpoole please don't edit out important parts of the question!

Comment: Excellent! Glad that you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't find a solutions, I would recommend you use http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/. I was looking for a Carousel recently, and found this the easiest and most easy to play around with.

This also prevented a jQuery Version Conflict which other Carousels were giving me.